# How to use Psbt on bitcoinjs-lib?

Tags: javascript, browser, ecmascript-6, bitcoin, bitcoinjs-lib

I am trying to create a raw transaction for sending to the blockchain. In doing so, I want to do this in a browser.

Where can I get `nonWitnessUtxo`?

All the information that I have outlined here, I found in the tests.
Am I doing the right thing?

```
const bitcoin = require('bitcoinjs-lib')
const testnet = bitcoin.networks.testnet
const keyPair = bitcoin.ECPair.makeRandom({ network: testnet })
const publicKey = keyPair.publicKey
const { address } = bitcoin.payments.p2pkh({
  pubkey: publicKey,
  network: testnet
})
const privateKey = keyPair.toWIF()
const psbt = new bitcoin.Psbt({ network: testnet })
const txid = '226a14d30cfd411b14bf20b7ffd211f7f206699690c54d456cc1bef70c2de5a6'
const key = bitcoin.ECPair.fromWIF(privateKey, testnet)
psbt.addInput({
  hash: txid,
  index: 0,
  nonWitnessUtxo: Buffer.from('Where can i get this?', 'hex')
})
psbt.addOutput({
  script: Buffer.from('mmpAPZSvhJs1NGw8UaJXEJ9vRByAxProUL', 'hex')
  value: 10000
})
psbt.signInput(0, key)
psbt.validateSignaturesOfInput(0)
psbt.finalizeAllInputs()
psbt.extractTransaction().toHex()
```

I would be grateful for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is for those looking for a way to create a transaction in the browser, but could not deal with the `bitcoinjs-lib`

I use `bitcore-lib` - https://www.npmjs.com/package/bitcore-lib

```
const bitcore = require('bitcore-lib')

const firstPrivateKey = new bitcore.PrivateKey()
const secondPrivateKey = new bitcore.PrivateKey() 

const wif = firstPrivateKey.toString()
const toAddress = secondPrivateKey.toAddress().toString()
const satoshiAmount = 10000

const privateKey = bitcore.PrivateKey.fromWIF(wif)
const sourceAddress = privateKey.toAddress(bitcore.Networks.testnet)
const targetAddress = bitcore.Address.fromString(toAddress)
const utxos = [
  {
    address: 'mywRqUpbENhbu5VsYDwiMTJouVK9g2ZEJQ',
    txid: '761693565e82ca176532c52a37fb38cd9f1eb0172a00562b394e60ede0b7df8a',
    vout: 1,
    scriptPubKey: '76a914ca133ceac705b723b91263aa163ea8a45954e49a88ac',
    amount: 0.0001,
    satoshis: 10000,
    height: 1578273,
    confirmations: 338
  }
]
const transaction = new bitcore.Transaction()

transaction.from(utxos)
transaction.to(targetAddress, Number(satoshiAmount))
transaction.change(sourceAddress)
transaction.sign(privateKey)

const serializedTX = tx.serialize()
```

Then you need send this `serializedTX` as raw transaction to bitcoin network.

P.S. This example does not work because there is an invalid is presented `utxos`. Get your `utxos` using `API`, such as `https://bitpay.com/api/addr/${sourceAddress}/utxo` and then everything will work.

Answer (score 3):

The `nonWitnessUtxo` is the full rawtransaction that you are referencing with the input txid.

Comment: `Where can i get this?` ?

Comment: You could request the rawtransaction from whatever protocol you are using by asking for it with the txid, for example with electrum's blockchain.transaction.get